# How can I make this Login case sensitive?

Tags: vb.net

```
 Private Sub btnSubmit_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSubmit.Click

        conn = New OleDbConnection("Provider = Microsoft.ace.Oledb.12.0; Data Source = C:\Users\matthew\Desktop\GSCS\Enrollment.accdb")
        conn.Open()

        Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("SELECT  * FROM Login WHERE UserName = '" & txtUserName.Text & "' AND [Password] = '" & txtPassword.Text & "'", conn)
        Dim dr As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader

        Dim userFound As Boolean = False

        While dr.Read()
            userFound = True
            UserName = dr("Username").ToString
            Password = dr("Password").ToString
            LevelOfAccess = dr("LevelOfAccess").ToString
        End While

        If txtUserName.Text = "" Or txtPassword.Text = "" Then
            MessageBox.Show("Some fields missing")

        ElseIf txtPassword.Text.Length < 6 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Password should consists of 6-12 characters", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK)

        ElseIf userFound = True Then

            Dim st As String = "INSERT INTO AuditTrail (Username, DateOfUsage, Activity) VALUES ('" & txtUserName.Text & "', '" & Date.Now & "', '" & li & "')"
            Dim cmd1 As New OleDbCommand(st, conn)
            cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery()

            If LevelOfAccess = 1 Then
                DisplayForm(Dashboard, Main.pnlMain)
                MessageBox.Show("Administrator")

            ElseIf LevelOfAccess = 2 Then
                DisplayForm(Dashboard1, Main.pnlMain)
                MessageBox.Show("Employee")
            End If

        Else
            MsgBox("Sorry, username or password not found", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Invalid Login")
        End If

        conn.Close()
    End Sub
```

This is my login code, can anybody help me how can I make it case sensitive? There are no error, but it is not casesensitive. Anyone who has the idea how I can make this case sensitive?

Comment: aw I copied the wrong one

Comment: Not using parameterized query is a capital mistake. (And this is a particular sensitive query) Too simple to bypass

Comment: Well - outside the huge SQL Injection attack vector (parametrized queries, use them, especially for this) .... then the solution depends on which database you use. SQL Server has case sensitive collations for example that you can use. But you should be hashing your passwords so they're case sensitive by default. Also you're claiming password should be 6-12 characters (why?) - but you're only checking for less than 6.

Comment: What about my favourite password `pass'; drop table login--`?

Comment: @Arvo that could not work here 'thanks' to the ms-access limitations

Comment: if I used a parameterized query will it be case sensitive?

Comment: Now your code is case sensitive. Using LIKE made it case insensitive. Usually the UserName is case insensitive but the password no. Did you test it again?

Comment: You should check in design mode in access that your fields are case sensitive...

Answer (score 0):

```
   String.Compare(str1, str2, True))
```

try to use string.compare method instead of just "=" Sign

like this:

`dim x as integer
x=String.Compare(str1, str2, False)
if x=0 then
'Put Codes Here If Password Is Correct
else 
'put Code Here IF password Is Incorrect
end if`

Comment: This has nothing to do with string comparison... The database is not storing data case sensitive that's the problem. = is a case sensitive comparer

Comment: ahh, You mean that StoringData In a case Sensitive, I thought it Was Retrieving Password Data From The Database And you want to Make it Case Sensitive When The User Type the Username Or Password

Comment: well I suppose so because I know MS Access is sometimes tricky with case sensitivity...